# impedir que as paginas sejam carregadas pelo navegador apos encerrar a sessão

Tags: php

Boa tarde , Pessoal.

É o seguinte estou desenvolvendo um sistema acadêmico, onde um usuário através de login e senha acessa o área correspondente a sua permissão, apos utilizar o mesmo deverá clicar em logout ou fechar a janela. só que ao fazer logout as paginas continuam sendo acessadas pelo botão voltar do navegador, preciso que as mesmas fiquem inacessíveis, sendo novamente acessadas atraves de login.

Alguém pode me ajudar nessa.

Comment: Você precisa explicar melhor como implementou essa lógica de controle de acesso. Mas basicamente precisa salvar na sessão o usuário logado, e verificar se esse dado existe na sessão antes de carregar cada página restrita.

Comment: bfavaretto,é o seguinte o usuario faz login e é direcionado par uma página especifica, ae ele navega pelas paginas do sistema ao voltar para a pagina inicial ele faz logout, se confiro realmente a sessão foi destruida mas as paginas visitadas continuam acessiveis pelo botão do navegador.

Comment: Posta o código onde inicializa e destrói a sessão...

Comment: Não sei como implementou suas sessões. Em cada início de requisição você deve verificar se o usuário está logado ou não, e quando não estiver, redirecionar para o login. No logout, o ideal é enviar um POST para a página de logout, e então redirecionar o usuário para uma página (usando GET mesmo). Uma pergunta similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354787/how-to-avoid-user-get-into-the-login-session-even-after-logging-out-by-clicking

Comment: @Magic Hat  onde posto o codigo

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo onde chamo esta função

Comment: não tem que fazer nada além de colar o código na página, a chamada da função está já no final do código

Comment: Dentro de sua pergunta tem um link [editar], clica copia teu código e cola, depois seleciona apenas teu código e clica nas chaves`{}` para a formatação...